# ”url(http://exapmle.com)”からurlを取り出すスマートな方法。

Tags: javascript, html

現在は

```
str = "url(http://exapmle.com)"
str.split("(")[1].split(")")[0] => "http://exapmle.com"
```

等としていますが、もうちょっとスマートな方法があるような気がします。

Comment: 正規表現を使ってはいかがでしょう？

Comment: `str.split(/url\((.+)\)/)[1]`

Comment: 例では、文字列の先頭から `url(...)` が始まり、余計な文字列が付いておらず、かつ1つしか現れない様ですが、これが確定しているかどうかで実装方法が異なります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

括弧があっても大丈夫なように書換え。マッチしなければ、元の文字列をそのまま返します。

```
var str = "url(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534359(v=vs.85).aspx)";
var m = str.match(/^url\((.*)\)$/i);
var url = m ? m[1]: str;
// => "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534359(v=vs.85).aspx"
```

Answer (score 3):

`slice`を使います

`str.slice(4,-1)`

Answer (score 1):

`replace`を使います。

`str.replace(/^url\((.*)\)$/g,"$1")`

Answer (score 1):

多少お節介ではありますが、用途を推察するに URL に引用符がついている可能性を考慮したほうがよいかもしれません。
その場合は、正規表現を利用して、以下のようにするとよいでしょう。

```
str.replace(/^url\(\s*(?:(["'])(.*)\1|((?:[^\(\)]|\\\(|\\\))*))\s*\)$/, "$2$3");
```

引用符が存在しない場合、URI に 括弧を含めるには、 "\" でエスケープする必要があります。
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri
ただし、上記のコードサンプルの場合、置換後にもエスケープ文字が残ってしまいます。

Comment: 質問文には書かれていませんがやはりCSSですよね。CSS3の場合は [CSS Syntax Module Level 3, 4.3.5. Consume a url token](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#consume-a-url-token) です。